# Android ToggleButton pause/resume issue

Tags: android, toggle

I have a problem with my ToggleButton.

The first time i click on it, it mutes the media sounds. The second time, it unmutes them. To save the ToggleButton's state i've used the onPause/onResume methods. But the problem is that if i launch the activity, then i press the toggle button, i pause it and when i finally resume it, the toggle button doesn't work anymore and the application remains muted. (Even if the state is saved)

My Activity part:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();


    if (on) {
         AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);

    } else {
        AudioManager aManager=(AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        aManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, false);


    }

}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    bundle.putBoolean("ToggleButtonState", ToggleButton.isChecked());

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ToggleButton.setChecked(bundle.getBoolean("ToggleButtonState",false));
}
```

I know i probably should use another pause/resume code somewhere, can you help? Thanks :)

Here's the log when i open the app, open the button's activity, click the button, pause the activity, resume it , click the button again and pause the activity again:

```
01-01 04:19:55.004: D/OpenGLRenderer(10766): Enabling debug mode 0

01-01 04:19:55.113: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41df9820 time:9273361

01-01 04:20:00.902: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.appquiz time:9279155

01-01 04:20:01.121: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41f99298 time:9279369

01-01 04:20:05.840: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41df9820 time:9284092

01-01 04:20:09.988: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.appquiz time:9288234

01-01 04:20:10.168: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41fbf7f0 time:9288414

01-01 04:20:20.566: I/ActivityManager(10766): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41df9820 time:9298814
```

Comment: have you tried outputting logs in your onresume and pause methods to see that at the time where it gets stuck muted, the value you have saved, is still the value you exited with ?

Comment: how do you get the bundle ?

Comment: Bundle: private static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

Comment: do you save it in the activity's state when the activity is destroyed?

Comment: With the onSaveInstanceState method? no i don't :/

Comment: when your activity is destroyed, and you don't save the state in some persistance, when you come back to it, oncreate runs again, and your bundle is empty, so the option for "ToggleButton" key is empty, thus returns false, and your toggle button remains mute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when your activity is destroyed, and you don't save the state in some persistance, when you come back to it, oncreate runs again, and your bundle is empty, so the option for "ToggleButton" key is empty, thus returns false, and your toggle button remains mute

Comment: I added the savedInstanceState method like that: http://www.beetxt.com/qUM/     but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: put it in shared preferences, saved instance state is to move between activities

Comment: onPause
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("my_settings",0).edit(); editor.putBoolean("ToggleButton",true/**whicheverState it should be here*/).commit(); and then
onResume
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_settings",0);
boolean ToggleButtonState = prefs.getBoolean("ToggleButton",true);